# Android Studio dex.DexException:

Tags: android

Randomly got this error during my build (debug or production) in the morning.

```
com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lcom/crashlytics/android/answers/shim/R
Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
>...
```

It has been 10hours and I have tried:

1) Updated my Android SDKs
[image]

2) Updated my Google Repository[image]

3) Updated everything else as well.

4) **Cleaned** and **Rebuild** the project with no errors.

5) Went through my external dependency tree, didn't find any duplicate libraries.

Here is my gradle content:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
  compileSdkVersion 25
  buildToolsVersion '25.0.0'

  defaultConfig {
    applicationId "######.####"
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 25
    versionCode 53
    versionName "1.2"
  }

  buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
  }
}

dependencies {
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.0.0'
compile 'com.androidmapsextensions:android-maps-extensions:2.3.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:10.2.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:10.2.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:10.2.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:10.2.1'
compile 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.5'
compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.0.0'
compile 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.9.2'
compile 'com.github.lzyzsd:circleprogress:1.1.0@aar'
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.7'
compile 'io.branch.sdk.android:library:2.+'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.2.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:10.2.1'
compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.+'
compile 'net.yslibrary.keyboardvisibilityevent:keyboardvisibilityevent:1.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.0.0'
compile 'com.edmodo:rangebar:1.0.0'
compile 'com.appyvet:materialrangebar:1.3'
compile 'com.facebook.fresco:fresco:0.14.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.2.1'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.0.0'
}


apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Running out of ideas and google result pages for a solution. Does anybody experienced find something wrong with the libraries I use or the versions?

Thanks!

Comment: remove `compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.0.0'` you have already added it ...in gradle

Comment: Removed, cleaned, rebuilt, same error :(

Answer (score 0):

remove this line = compile 'com.android.support:design:25.0.0'

if it doesn't work please add

```
dexOptions {
preDexLibraries = false }
```

to your build.gradle file

Comment: can you add this line  - multiDexEnabled true - below to versionName "1.2" and try to build it again? @KasparTr

Answer (score 0):

Solution found.

Looking at the error I googled and found [this](https://github.com/BranchMetrics/android-branch-deep-linking/issues/415).

Then went to the Branch documentation and found this [here](https://dev.branch.io/getting-started/sdk-integration-guide/guide/android/) which stated:

> Note that if you don’t plan to use the Fabric Answers integration, you
>   can use the following line:

```
compile ('io.branch.sdk.android:library:2.+') {
   exclude module: 'answers-shim'
}
```

This answers-shim is also in the stacktrace.

I wonder where is that module then duplicated?